# Background App Refresh IOS 9.3

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I increase the `backgroundTimeRemaining`? The default is 180s. But I need to update steps on server every 30 minutes. I have tried many guides, but it isn't working for me.

Comment: Tha maximum time is 3 mins. You cannot go further.You can try push notifications form server.

Comment: What is it that you will update? steps? as in Location update ?

Comment: You should paste the relevant code of what you're trying so that also other could benefit from this.